# Entity Framework Adds existing foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am having a problem with getting a relationship to work how I would like with Entity Framework. The situation is as follows.

There are a number of departments in a store; food, drink, entertainment, etc.

There are a number of employees who work in a store. Employees are allowed to work in one or more departments.

The classes I have are:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeDeparmentMapping> DeparmentMappings { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDeparmentMapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

I am using code first and my modelbuilder looks something like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasMany(e => e.DeparmentMappings).WithRequired(e => e.Employee);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeDeparmentMapping>().HasRequired(edm => edm.Department);
    }
```

I am having a problem when I try to add EmployeeDeparmentMappings, like so:

```
public void SomeMethod(EmployeeDeparmentMapping edm)
{
    MyDbContext myDb = new MyDbContext();
    myDb.EmployeeDepartmentMappings.Add(emd);
    myDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

The exceptions gets thrown is a PRIMARY KEY violation on the Department table, this is because the department in the EmployeeDepartmentMappings object may already exist in the databse but not in the DbContext.

I tried the following:

```
public void SomeMethod(EmployeeDeparmentMapping edm)
{
    MyDbContext myDb = new MyDbContext();
    myDb.Departments.Attach(emd.Department);
    myDb.EmployeeDepartmentMappings.Add(emd);
    myDb.SaveChanges();

}
```

But this throws an `InvalidOperationException`, the changes get saved to db but the context is apparently broken.

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Can you post the full error message from the `InvalidOperationException` that is thrown?

Comment: Not much time to explain now, but try to make `Employee` and `Department` in `EmployeeDeparmentMapping` virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDeparmentMapping> DeparmentMappings { get; set; }
```

and

```
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

virtual because they are just for navigating purposes they already exist

Comment: Changing them to virtual seems to have had no effect, the same to problems still occur :(